# Wordpress comments not showing up on posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on rebuilding a friends website however cannot get the wordpress comments to show up on posts, I have tried disabling all plugins, switching themes (even default themes) but the comments still do not show up.

This is the first time I've worked on a wordpress site and all the posts I can see from people with the same issue resolved it either by disabling plugins or switching themes (usually issues with `single.php` which the theme I'm using does not have that file).

Any ideas?

[URL for the site](http://happybody.co.nz)

Comment: There's a per post setting to allow/disallow comments. Also, maybe use the default theme to see if comments appear there.

Comment: Sorry, just read you alreay used the default theme. I'll take a look at your site, could be comments are just hidden by CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there are no comments on that site, the "Comments feed" is empty: http://happybody.co.nz/comments/feed/

Comment: But without the comment section showing at the bottom of a/all posts comments cannot be entered so the comments feed would be empty?

Comment: Ok, in your question you said comments are not showing, so I assumed there already were comments for posts. So, the comments section is not showing under the posts?

Comment: So I've just figured out why the comments section does not show up, when I recreated all the posts fro a cached copy of the site from http://archive.org/web/ I never ticked the box on each post under "discussion" for "allow comments". Once I figured that out I felt very embarrassed :p    Is there a way to have that set as allow by default?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked SETTINGS > DISCUSSIONS > Allow people to post comments on new articles - or any of the other Comments Settings there?

Comment: Yes, these are the settings that are checked,  Allow people to post comments on new articles, Comment author must fill out name and e-mail, Enable threaded (nested) comments  levels deep, A comment is held for moderation, Comment must be manually approved

Comment: @NYCBilly That's not an answer, that's a question itself. Use the comments to ask OP questions

Comment: Wtf... I answer a lot of my questions that way, many of them get voted the answer... I'm not answering anyone now for a month at least... bye...

Answer (score 0):

In the file sigle-post.php or like some Think similar in the theme folder, find the function get_post_commets($post->ID) and delete.

May be exist an foreach to show a result of the function one by one.

Get lucky.

Comment: How would deleting `get_post_commets($post->ID)` show the comments?

Comment: Them  create a foreach with the function. Sorry dont read ok .

Answer (score 0):

Find get_post_comments() function ... In wordpress site support.

Answer (score 0):

So I've just figured out why the comments section does not show up, when I recreated all the posts from a cached copy of the site from archive.org/web I never ticked the box on each post under "discussion" for "allow comments".